# Jquery / Javascript Submenu Color Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, hover, drop-down-menu

I have another problem in a jquery dropdown menu.

In my example (link in the bottom) I want that when I hover the 3ºlevel Submenu the **text color** of the current submenu item stays in hover state (color yellow in example).

[Link To Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbml/JTwwY/) with complete Code

I have comments in the code to explain where is the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [updated your fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JTwwY/28/) to fix the problem.

I shifted the hover from `ul.submenu li a` to just be `ul.submenu li` so that when its submenu2 was hovered over it didn't call the unhover function.  I then applied the styles in the functions to the `.children('a')` tags, like so:

```
$('ul.submenu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('a').css({
        color: '#eff803'
    });

    $(this).find(".submenu li:first a").stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#0d0167'
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).children('a').css({
        color: '#ffffff'
    });

    $(this).find(".submenu li:first a").stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: '#0000FF'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the solution that I search !!

Answer (score 0):

for a start, avoid `css()` where you can. you're better off using `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. define a hover class that contains the colours you want then (assuming your menu is not inside another `<ol>` or `<ul>`) use something like

```
$('.menu a').hover(function() {
  var $path = $(this).parents('li').find('> a').not(this);
  $(this).closest('.menu').find('a').not($path).removeClass('hover');
  $path.addClass('hover');
  //code that animates to the colours in your hover class
  $(this).addClass('hover').css('');//make it stick
});
```

edit: sorry didn't think about the fading in of styles

Comment: Thanks, is a possibility. You now if there is a way, without addClass of doing this ? $(this).find(something).css('#ffffff');